# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of this Observable is already released

Tags: couchbase, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I am using Spring web flux + Reactive Couchbase 6.0.

After deploying my code, I am getting below two errors off and on.

**First Error:**

```
[QueryEndpoint]: Got error while consuming KeepAliveResponse. java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeTimeoutTimedWithFallback$TimeoutMainSubscriber.onTimeout(OnSubscribeTimeoutTimedWithFallback.java:166)
```

**Second Error:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of this Observable (queryRow.59645c34-2faf-496f-b0b1-5b63b7f88f6b) is already released. Subscribe earlier or tune the CouchbaseEnvironment#autoreleaseAfter() setting.\n\tat com.couchbase.client.core.utils.UnicastAutoReleaseSubject$OnSubscribeAction.call
```

I have gone through many similar topics but got confused a bit.

I have below questions:

1: Do the above errors indicate the same issue?

2: If I set autoreleaseAfter and query timeout at CouchbaseEnvironment level, would it solve these errors? If yes does it have any performance implications?

3 : I have gone through this https://forums.couchbase.com/t/n1ql-query-with-adhoc-false-query-runs-into-illegalstateexception-the-content-of-this-observable-is-already-released/11004

here @ subhashni indicating that it is a bug and have been resolved.
But I am facing these errors in Couchbase 6.0.

Kindly help me out

Comment: We just released yesterday a new version of SDK 2, can you please try it again?